# Bamboo SCP Task failing to upload to SolarWinds SFTP/SCP Server

Tags: scp, bamboo

We have a Job configured in Bamboo (version 5.5.1 build 4305 on Windows Server 2008 R2) which uses the SCP Task to copy a file to our central file server which is running SolarWinds SFTP/SCP Server (version 1.0.4.9 on Windows Server 2008 R2)

When the Job runs it fails with the following error:

> net.schmizz.sshj.xfer.scp.SCPException: EOF while expecting response
>   to protocol message. Additional info: `scp: Failed to open file '/'

where `'/'` is the Remote Path configured in the SCP Task.

Whatever we change `'/'` to, it fails with the same error, just the path changes.

I have tested using PuTTY SCP (pscp.exe) using the account which the Bamboo service runs under and the command completes fine.

Why can't Bamboo SCP Task copy the file?

Comment: Have you tried to escape the '/' ? Also, can you provide the full setting for the scp task?

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be \ for a windows server

Comment: The SCP task wouldn't save with that.

Comment: Scrap my previous comment, it should be / as I recently found out. Also i'm using Cygwin for SSH & SCP. Then on the remote path I set it to something like this; /cygdrive/c/www/public_html/ to find the path I used Putty to SSH onto the server followed by ls -la